# Getting info from UITextField inside a cell

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField inside a custom cell. I have a button in the viewController that I would like to turn red when there is text in the UITextField in the cell. I have created buttons like this when the UITextField has in the viewController but not when the UITextView is inside the cell. How would I go about doing this.

Here is how I would do it is the UITextField was inside the viewController -

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {

    if (self.schoolText.text.length > 0) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }else{

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:193/255.5 green:193/255.0 blue:193/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UITextFieldDelegate` method below to check for the length

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

One thing to note is that the above method is called before the text field actually updates its text, so to overcome that you can use the following line.

`[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string].length`

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, I assume that you have created a custom `UITableViewCell` with an `UITextField` as it's outlet named `theTextField`. and you have connected the `UITextField` in the storyboard to your custom cell.

now when you are populating the data into the cell in 
`-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you have to do either one of these:

if you want to change the color of the button at the moment that text changes, use:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:cell.theTextField]`

while `textChanged:` is a method like this:

`- (void) textChanged:(NSNotification *) notification`

or if the delegate is enough, just use `cell.theTextField.delegate = self;`

that's it